# Django Signals, how to know when an update happen?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

The url of my post object must be:

city-the-title-of-the-post-POST.ID, to achieve this when the obj is created I am using a post_save signal

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post, dispatch_uid="update_stock_count")
def criar_slug(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        string = (instance.city+" "+instance.title+" "+str(instance.id))
        instance.slug = slugify(string)
        instance.save()
```

It is working fine! Now the problem. If I go to the django admin when I change the post.title then save the post, the slug of course will not change. So I am wondering how I could catch this update signal, how I could automatic change the slug attribute when updating the obj.

Thanks

Comment: Well, you've explicitly put your slug logic inside `if created`, which won't be true when the instance already exists, surely?

Comment: Yes. I did it because I don't know how to use a signal for django uptade action. And by the fact it could create another object, but I am not sure. The post_save do not allow it, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=Post, dispatch_uid="update_stock_count")
def criar_slug(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if kwargs['created'] or 'city' in kwargs['update_fields'] or 'title' in kwargs['update_fields'] :
        string = (instance.city+" "+instance.title+" "+str(instance.id))
        instance.slug = slugify(string)
        instance.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to remove if created flag so that you can change the slug field.

Refer following solution

Use init signal to store previous value of filed so that you can check that field modified or not in post signal.

```
@receiver(post_init, sender=Post)
def lead_post_init(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance._previous_city = instance.city
    instance._previous_title = instance.title

@receiver(post_save, sender=Post, dispatch_uid="update_stock_count")
def criar_slug(sender, instance, created,**kwargs):
    if instance._previous_city != instance.city or instance._previous_title != instance.title:
        string = (instance.city+" "+instance.title+" "+str(instance.id))
        instance.slug = slugify(string)
        instance.save()
```

Hope this is helps you